# Angular Form Validating Image with Data URL (base64 string)

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-forms, angular-validation

I am using angular 4 and using reactive forms in ionic.

What I want is for the user to upload an image from device gallery.

Here is what I have in my controller.

```
  this.imageForm=this.formbuilder.group({
  image1:['',[Validators.required]],
})
```

In my template, I have the following.

```
   <img *ngIf="imageForm.controls.image1.value" formControlName="image1" src="{{imageForm.controls.image1.value}}">
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'image1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the correct way to get the value of a Form Control. This is what you want in both your *ngIf and src:

`imageForm.get('image1').value`

Comment: the error was due to `formControlName="image1"` I remove it and now it is working

Comment: Oh ya, <img> doesn't have an input, so that would be the problem. You should get in the habit of using `form.get()` though, especially since you are not using ? to check to see if the form, control, or value property even exists.

Comment: So how does one add form validation to img tag?

Comment: Give me an example and I could give you a way to do it. You won't be able to make it a Form Control and attach Validators to it.

Comment: Take the same example above. I want to check if the user has uploaded a pic or not and perform valid/ dirty validations if the image tag has a dataurl.

Comment: So if the user uploads a picture, you only want to show something if it was uploaded and that there is a dataurl, or do you want to call a function?

Comment: Yes. Somewhere along those lines. I want to check it as an input. If the image has been uploaded the form will be valid if not then invalid.